# Google Search Appliance - GSA - configuration issue

Tags: google-search-appliance

I want to use GSAClient to access our company google search appliance project and retrieve searching result, but I don't get the configuration working at all.

The web UI is: http://kb.juniper.net

So in order to make GSAClientDemo working, how should I set:

1. HOSTNAME
2. SETTING_FRONTEND

Do I have to ask GSA admin for the settings?

```
// target GSA's hostname
    private static final String HOSTNAME = "kb.juniper.net";
    // query string to search for
    private static final String QUERY_STRING = "juno";
 // The value for the frontend configured for the GSA
    // (If you dont know this, ask GSA admin for correct value for your target GSA.)
    private static final String SETTING_FRONTEND = "InfoCenter";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        GSAClient client = new GSAClient(HOSTNAME); 
        GSAQuery query = new GSAQuery();

        // typical way to generate query term.
        GSAQueryTerm term = new GSAQueryTerm(QUERY_STRING);
        query.setQueryTerm(term);
        System.out.println("Searching for: "+query.getQueryString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Hostname is the GSA domain name or ip
Frontend is not required

Complete example is here:

http://gsa-japi.sourceforge.net/onemin-tut.html

Comment: well it's still required for client parameter

Answer (score 0):

> > Do I have to ask GSA admin for the settings?

Yes. You need to check with your GSA admin for the HOST and front_end information. Only they can tell you. Unless, you know how to use GSA and are permitted to get the information for yourself.